# Why is virtualenv creating symlinks to my primary python interpreter?

Tags: virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

When I convert a directory into a virtual environment using virtualenv, three directories are created: bin, include and lib.

bin is the only directory I understand, (to my knowledge) it holds the standalone interpreter and all of the dependencies I want isolated from my global environment.

include and lib are both full of symlinks, with a handful of non-linked files in the lib folder; why are these symlinks present? What is their purpose? How do they serve my virtual environment?
I've checked the documentation, and if the answer is there, I missed it.
Can someone enlighten me (or point me at the right documentation)?

I'm running an Ubuntu server 18.04 build.
When I create my environment, I don't add any - or -- args, it looks like this:

```
    $ virtualenv <directory_name>
```

or

```
    $ virtualenv .
```

Comment: I noticed this today too using venv. I don't fully understand what Python virtual environments are all about. But I was under the impression they were meant to be self contained. I was surprised to see that the `python` file in it was just a symlink to my globally installed pyenv version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links bring standard library into the virtualenv. They are required because python in the virtualenv doesn't have access to the global `lib/pythonX.Y` directory. The alternative is to copy the library into the virtualenv but that would take more space and wouldn't make anything better.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. I thought that by having the interpreter in the 'bin' folder, it has everything it needs to run. Why would a project based on python 2.7 need symlinks to 3.5 (an ignorant example, I am new and only work in 3.7. Trying to understand the fundamentals)

Comment: *python 2.7 need symlinks to 3.5* It doesn't. Where did you see such symlinks? Looks like a broken virtualenv.

Comment: I need to articulate my question better: why does my virtual environment need any directory other than the bin directory? My understanding (which may be erroneous) is that the interpreter is housed in the bin folder. Am I wrong, and the lib and include folders are part of the python interpreter within the virtual env, and the symlinks are only created because I didn't specify a version of python?

Comment: *why does my virtual environment need any directory other than the bin directory?* Because python virtual environments protect from global `site-packages` but everything else (bin, include, lib) should be in every virtualenv. *lib and include folders are part of the python interpreter* They aren't part of the interpreter, they are part of the environment required to run the interpreter (lib) and compile extensions (include). *the symlinks are only created because I didn't specify a version of python?* No, they are always created.

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback. Thanks a bundle for your time and effort. My takeaway: Python needs the three directories to be fully functioning; the default setup is to utilize your systems everything-but site packages. If I want further seperation, I have to populate the lib and include files with the actual files that are symlinked. Thank you!