# Why is there a red question mark next to my python files in a newly created virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

/Users/"MYNAME"/Documents/Py/tezEnv

This is the file path to the virtual environment called 'tezEnv'. I have changed part of the file path to "MYNAME" to keep identity.

When I look in this bin folder I can see the following (red exclamation marks) (Please see screenshot). As a bigger picture would this be causing import errors for any scripts that I run using this virtual environment?

[image: Red Exclamation Marks]

Comment: It will probably be because they are symlinks. What program are you using to view this directory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754666/why-is-virtualenv-creating-symlinks-to-my-primary-python-interpreter may be useful to you.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a cloud sync tool such as Dropbox, and it is unable to sync symlinks?

Comment: For the first comment from @bigkeefer sorry I'm not that technical but I am unsure what you mean which program? I used the terminal to create the virtual environment then just looked at it in the apple finder and saw the exclamation marks.

Thanks

Comment: For the second comment @NickODell I do sync a folder that contains the folder with the virtual environment in to google drive. Is that what may be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I haven't seen/used Macs for many years, so I didn't recognise the look of Finder. As @NickODell said the exclamation marks are probably telling you that it can't sync symlinks (as you have confirmed you're using Google Drive).

Comment: To answer your last question in your original post, it shouldn't cause any issues at all on the computer you originally created the venv on (as the symlinks are there just fine), but you'll encounter problems on another machine that has synced from Google Drive (as the symlinks will be missing). To rectify that you'd have to create the symlinks manually on your other machine (assuming you have the same version of Python on those machines).

Comment: Having said all that,  my gut is saying that a venv being synced all the time may cause issues/clashes,  even on the original machine. I've never tried it myself.